# How can we convert string into object

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/vjnsd5wo/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
            {
                localStorage.setItem("contacts",JSON.stringify(details));
                var str=localStorage.getItem("contacts");
                $("#div1").text(str);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#div1").text("Sorry ur browser does not support");
            }
        });
    });
```

Once analyse the program in fiddle and please can any1 say how to convert string intoo object

Comment: You can convert it by calling JSON.parse try to add the following line before assigning the str to the DIV str = JSON.parse(str); Try this https://jsfiddle.net/vjnsd5wo/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it by calling JSON.parse

```
localStorage.setItem("contacts",JSON.stringify(details));
var str=localStorage.getItem("contacts");
str = JSON.parse(str); 
$("#div1").text(str);
```

Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/vjnsd5wo/1/